# nginx location rule interference

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, nginx-location

I have this Nginx rule:

```
location /fr {
  rewrite ^/(fr)(?:/([^/]+))?$ /$2?lang=$1 last;
}
```

I have pages such as:

`example.com/en/some-page`

`example.com/fr/some-page`

`example.com/fr`

`...`

But I also have a page which starts by `fr`:

`example.com/free-plan // doesn't work`

`example.com/fr/free-plan // doesn't work either`

How can I modify my Nginx rule so that the `/fr` rule doesn't interference with my `free-plan` page?

Ps: I use PHP and rules to service page without the extension:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @extensionless-php {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you treat `/fr` as a special case and use `location /fr/` to avoid side-effects from pages that begin with `fr`.

For example:

```
location = /fr {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /?lang=$1 last;
}
location /fr/ {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Hi Richard, this fixed part of the problem. However when going to `example.com/fr`, it doesn't take `fr` as the `lang` variable. Pages like `example.com/fr/some-page` work however.

Comment: Sorry, I was capturing the leading `/`. You could probably hardwire the parameter using `rewrite ^ /?lang=fr last;`. I wasn't sure if you needed a generalised answer.